# WCF MaxStringContentLength

Tags: asp.net, wcf, arguments, max, maxstringcontentlength

I've maxed out my `maxStringContentLength` when passing arguments from WCF to WCF.

No biggie, I'll just up the value. But I have a question before I do:

Is that default 8192 size in bits, bytes, characters, words or what?!?!

I've been here (`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionaryreaderquotas.maxstringcontentlength.aspx`), but apparently it's a big secret and nobody's supposed to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in bytes.  The default is 8K.

**Edited To Add**
Actually, the documentation in one place says character, so characters is probably the more correct answer.  Bytes works though if you're dealing with the normal 255 ASCII characters, as one byte = one character.

Answer (score 1):

The length is in chracters, as mentioned by Tim (it's essentially the result of string.Length). One more thing to add - the correlation between bytes and characters really depends on the encoding which is used. For normal "text" XML, if you use UTF-8 each character can be represented by 1, 2 or 3 bytes. If you use UTF-16, it'll be always 2 bytes per character. If you use the binary XML (i.e., with the BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement), it's possible that you have some *dictionary strings* in the content, and they can take only a few bytes, but they can be expanded to large string values - and MaxStringContentLength is one of the quotas prevents a malicious client from sending a small number of bytes that cause a large allocation of memory in the server.